# Does the speed of light determine how slow time can move?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time, observers, time-dilation

Since moving faster makes time move slower. Does that mean that there is an absolute minimum rate at which time passes? If so. Is there also a maximum?

Comment: Time is that which the clocks show. Does my clock care about your relative motion? No.

Answer (score 2):

Time doesn't move, we do. That is, the best model we have right now of the universe is that of a 4 dimensional spacetime. Objects take paths ("world lines") through spacetime. The lengths of the objects' paths between points in spacetime ("events") correspond to the time experienced by those objects.

Two objects in constant relative motion have world lines that are at angles to one another. This means that each one measures the other's clock to be slower. There's no absolute answer to which one is right: it just depends on what coordinates you use.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, massless particles which goes at the speed of light does not experience time as it "slows" so much that it can not flow anymore (of course this point is subtle and you will find other threads on this website explaining it in better details).
As such, the absolute minimum at which time passes is when it does not pass at all! If the speed-of-light were different, this "minimum" would be the same but it would be associated with a different speed for massless particles.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, inverse of Lorentz factor :

[image]

shows that proper time lapsing ratio ${\Delta t}/{\Delta t^{'}}$ approaches zero as $v\to c$. So basically time stops for such object, and it's lifetime approches infinity. Hence answer to your question that absolute minimum time ticking rate is $0$.

However, objects with rest mass (me,you and any barionic matter) can't reach that much time slowdown ratio, even theoretically, because for speeding up to $c$ any finite mass object (even $1\mu g$ or less) requires infinite force and/or infinite energy source supply, which is unrealistic. Hence we always will remain "slow creatures" to photon.

Answer (score 0):

> Since moving faster makes time move slower.

Suppose you move fast in a journey from Earth to Neptune for example, and there are atomic clocks there synchronized with clocks here at Earth. Remember that velocity is relative. From the point of view of the ship, the Earth is receding and Neptune is approaching, both very fast.

But it doesn't matter the frame you choose to describe the movement. When the ship relative velocity with respect to Earth and Neptune, (whose relative velocity is very small compared to light), tends to light speed, the time of travel recorded by the ship clock tends to zero.

Of course, the clocks in Neptune will show a bigger time of travel, and the limit is the time for the light does that same travel.

So, the minimum limit is zero, even while it is never reached.